# Does Polyak-Lojasiewicz (PL) condition hold for convex quadratic functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, quadratic-forms

**Definition(Polyak-Lojasiewicz (PL) condition)**

If Polyak-Lojasiewicz (PL) condition is met for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, then the following holds for some $\mu>0$
$$\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2 \geq \mu(f(x) - f(x^*))$$
where $f(x^*)$ is the optimal value of the function.

---

**Question:**

---

Does PL condition hold for $f(x)=\|Ax-b\|^2$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times n}$ where $n> N$? In other words, does the following hold:
$$\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2 \geq \mu f(x)$$
because $f(x^*)=0$ and we have infinitely many $x^*$.

---

**My try:**

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|Ay-b\|^2
&=
\|A(y-x+x)-b\|^2
\\
&=\|Ax-b + A(y-x)\|^2
\\
&=\|Ax-b\|^2+\langle2(Ax-b),A(y-x)\rangle+\|A(y-x)\|^2
\\
&=\|Ax-b\|^2+\langle2A^{\top}(Ax-b),y-x\rangle+\|A(y-x)\|^2
\\
&=f(x)+\langle\nabla f(x),y-x\rangle+\|A(y-x)\|^2
\end{aligned}
$$

---

How can I continue? (Prove or disprove)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $f(x^*) = 0$ does not necessarily hold. To see this, we consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $b = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. In this case $b$ is not in the range of $A$ and thus we have $f(x) > 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Thus, your goal should be to show
$$
\frac{1}{2} ||\nabla f(x)||^2 \geq \mu(f(x) - f^*)
$$

As in your approach we obtain
$$
f(y) = f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle + \frac{1}{2} || A(y-x)||^2.
$$
To continue from this approach, you can consider $y = x_p$ as the projection of $x$ onto the set of minimizers of $f$ obtaining
$$
f^* = f(x_p) = f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), x_p - x\rangle + \frac{1}{2} || A(x_p  -x)||^2.
$$

Then, show that $f$ is weak strong convex ([Karimi](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04636.pdf)) by showing
$$
|| A(x_p - x) ||^2 \geq \mu ||x_p - x||^2.
$$
(To show this, it is helpful to consider the singular value decomposition of $A$).

This implies that $f$ satisfies the PL condition as shown in [Karimi](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04636.pdf).

Comment: Your proof is not correct. If $A$ is not full rank, $\mu$ could be zero.