# Does the Polyak-Lojasiewicz (PL) condition hold for this class of convex functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, convex-analysis

Upon reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4624401) post that shows quadratic convex functions satisfy the PL condition, I was curious if this can be extended to a broader class of functions. In particularly, I had two classes, one is a generalization of the other.

1. Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed, convex set. Define the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ as $$f(x) = d^2 (x,C) = \inf_{y \in C} \|x - y\|^2$$ Does this function satisfy the PL condition?
2. Let $d : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, \infty)$ be a convex metric. Again, let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed, convex set and define the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ as $$f(x) = d^2 (x,C) = \inf_{y \in C} d^2(x,y)$$ Does this function satisfy the PL condition?

Comment: It holds for **strongly** convex functions. That's a broader class of functions, indeed....

Comment: As for your specific question, I don't think this can be true without further conditions  on C. Have you tried a few examples ? E.g when C is a halfspace versus closed unit ball.